# How to append text into file in another package in java

Tags: java

I have a question about appending text to file which is in another package than the class. I have package called resources, and there are a files. The class where I want to have a code is in package readfile. I tryed a lot of possibilities but anything does not work. I'm enclosing my code. Sorry for my English.

```
try{
   PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new File(this.getClass().getResource("/resources/Files/conv").getPath()));
   writer.append("Some text");
   writer.close();
} catch (IOException ioe) {
   System.err.println("IOException: " + ioe.getMessage());    
}
```

Comment: Btw. conv is without .txt extension because I'm using Linux.

Comment: If the file is a resource, you should not try to write anything to it. A resource is meant to be part of the application itself, embedded in its jar/war file. If you want to treat it as writable a file, it should not be embedded into the application, and should not be in a directory that is in the classpath.

Comment: So where should be writeable files? I'm new to file system in java.

Comment: What is this writable file used for? If it's used to save data, just as a word processor would use a file to save a document, then ask the user for the file path. If it's used to save user preferences automatically, it could be in the user's home/.yourapplication directory.

Comment: In file there are units for converting. User can add unit so I need to write into files (kg, g, km, m, etc.).

Comment: Then I would probably use a file in <HOME>/.yourapplication to store that (or only the custom units).

Comment: So, I need to make a installation for user which will make application folder and finally there will copy files to home folder (/home)? In this case I will be able to use absolute paths. And what if the user will delete these files from this application folder? And what if the user don't want to install this program by installation?

Comment: You don't need to install anything. When your application needs to save the units, you check if the directory and file exists, create them if needed, then save. If the user chooses to delete hiw own files, then it the application will behave as if those files were never saved, i.e. as the first time it was used.

Comment: Everything works fine now.